# Capture image from webcam and convert to base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64, getusermedia

I need to capture an image from a web camera and convert to base64. Should be able to capture multiple frames and concatenate them and again convert to base 64.   This code works well for capturing but converting it to base64 seems to be an issue.

```
<html>
<body>
<center> 
<body>
<div id="container">
<video width="200" height="200" autoplay="true" id="video">
</video>
</div>
<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button>  <br> </br>
<canvas id="canvas" style="overflow:auto"></canvas>
<br></br>
<p> Image Converted to String: </p>
<p id="printresult"></p>
</center>
<script>
var video = document.querySelector("#video");
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}

function capture() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');     
var video = document.getElementById('video');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200,200);  
canvas.toBlob() = (blob) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
    };

}
document.getElementById("printresult").innerHTML = resultb64;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Answer (score 10):

https://jsfiddle.net/qfaeb3tL/1/

`canvas.toDataURL()` gives  u base64 string

```
 var video = document.querySelector("#video");
 if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch(function (err0r) {
          console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
 }
 var resultb64="";
 function capture() {        
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');     
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 200;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200,200);  
    document.getElementById("printresult").innerHTML = canvas.toDataURL(); 
 }
  document.getElementById("printresult").innerHTML = resultb64;
```

gives you base64 string. I created fiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [canvas.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) method and edit `capture` function to:

```
function capture() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');     
  var video = document.getElementById('video');

  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 200;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200,200);  

  document.getElementById("printresult").innerHTML = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```js
var video = document.querySelector("#video");

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
      video.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function (err0r) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!");
    });
}

function capture() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');     
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 200;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 200,200);  
  
  document.getElementById("printresult").innerHTML = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<video width="200" height="200" autoplay="true" id="video">
</video>
</div>
<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button>  <br> <br/>
<canvas id="canvas" style="overflow:auto"></canvas>
<br><br/>
<p> Image Converted to String: </p>
<p id="printresult"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a temp canvas. Just feed the data blob to a `FileReader` and get back the dataUrl you need

```
    const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);

    imageCapture.takePhoto().then((blob) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            var image = reader.result; // here's the dataUrl
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately ImageCapture is still experimental and not supported by several browsers like Firefox or Safari. Anyway, excellent proposal +1